# How to Convert ddmmyyyy to year(Date)?

Tags: obiee

I am new to OBIEE
I have date in ddmmyyyy format .
How can i create Year, Quarter, Month as separate fields out of that?

Example:
Order_date
21/11/2017
02/09/2016

OutPut
Year
2017
2016

Month
11
09

Comment: There should be month() and year() as a function.

Comment: I tried in that way but its not working

Comment: You have to be a bit more precise: What is not working? Please provide some code.

Answer (score 2):

In OBIEE a time value (i.e. now()) evaluates to **quarter** of year as:

```
qarter_of_year(now())
```

to **year** as:

```
year(now())
```

to **month** as

```
month(now())
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Christian - just use the actual OBI functions!

If it doesn't work you are probably not working with actual DATE data types but some numerical or varchar types.